# How to apply side effects in a swiftui ViewBuilder

Tags: ios, swiftui, viewbuilder

I am trying to render a simple `Text()` and apply an arbitrary number of different styles .
This is my code:

```
struct Cell {
    var content: String
    var style: TextStyle
}

@ViewBuilder
func styledText(cell: Cell) -> some View {
    if (cell.style.contains(TextStyle.rtl)) {
        Text(cell.content)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
            .lineSpacing(10)
    } else if (cell.style.contains(TextStyle.customFont)) {
        Text(cell.content).font(.custom("MyFont", size: 19))
    } else if (cell.style.contains(TextStyle.pinkColour)) {
        Text(cell.content).foregroundStyle(Color(UIColor.systemPink))
    } else {
        Text(cell.content)
    }
}
```

You can see from the above that only one branch can execute in the above function. But in my app, several styles could be applied (e.g. BOTH `customFont` and `pinkColour`). How do I achieve this?

### What I tried

```
@ViewBuilder
func styledText(cell: Cell) -> some View {
    var text = Text(cell.content)
    if (cell.style.contains(TextStyle.rtl)) {
        text = text
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
            .lineSpacing(10)
    } else if (cell.style.contains(TextStyle.customFont)) {
        text = text.font(.custom("MyFont", size: 19))
    } else if (cell.style.contains(TextStyle.pinkColour)) {
        text = text.foregroundStyle(Color(UIColor.systemPink))
    }
    text
}
```

As far as I understand (I'm new to Swift), every branch must result in a return value so the above does not work.

I also tried not using `@ViewBuilder` at all, but I cannot get my code to type check. I get errors such as `Cannot assign value of type 'some View' (result of 'Self.font') to type 'some View' (type of 'text')`

What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of `@ViewBuilder` try making a `ViewModifier` struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract a view modifier for each style, which will take a `Bool` and decide whether to return a modified view, or `self`.

```
@ViewBuilder
func styledText(cell: Cell) -> some View {
    Text(cell.content)
        .isRtl(cell.style.contains(.rtl))
        .isCustomFont(cell.style.contains(.customFont))
        .isPinkColor(cell.style.contains(.pinkColor))
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func isRtl(_ enabled: Bool) -> some View {
        if enabled {
            self.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
                .lineSpacing(10)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func isCustomFont(_ enabled: Bool) -> some View {
        if enabled {
            self.font(.custom("MyFont", size: 19))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func isPinkColor(_ enabled: Bool) -> some View {
        if enabled {
            self.font(.custom("MyFont", size: 19))
        } else {
            self.foregroundStyle(.pink)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, always apply all the modifiers, and use some default values when particular `TextStyle`s are not in `style`.

```
func styledText(cell: Cell) -> some View {
    let isRtl = cell.style.contains(.rtl)
    let isCustomFont = cell.style.contains(.customFont)
    let isPink = cell.style.contains(.pinkColor)
    Text(cell.content)
        .frame(maxWidth: isRtl ? .infinity : nil, alignment: isRtl ? .leading : .center)
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, isRtl ? .rightToLeft : .leftToRight)
        .lineSpacing(isRtl ? 10 : 3)
        .font(isCustomFont ? .custom("MyFont", size: 19) : .body)
        .foregroundStyle(isPink ? AnyShapeStyle(.pink) : AnyShapeStyle(.opacity(1.0)))
}
```